# How to use a Proxy when using Privoxy?

Tags: privoxy

We have a HTTP/HTTPS proxy that we need to use by default, call it XY.

But: I need to push my traffic through Privoxy (on my local PC) before handing the web traffic to XY. How to do this? I can install Privoxy and I know the address/port of XY, but how to configure Privoxy to use XY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the upstream/parent/forward server. Just check the privoxy [configuration](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html). It's straightforward.

Comment: vi /etc/privoxy/config # append this:
forward   /      proxy.address.com:8080